# Unlisting a dataframe from a list of a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

[image]

I want to extract a dataframe from a list that is also inside a list. Also some dataframes have different number of columns than others. This is what i have used without success.
Name of the first list is comments.

```
df <- do.call(rbind.fill,comments)
```

When i try

```
df <- do.call(rbind.fill,comments[[1]])
```

it does work, but i would like for all the dataframes to be together as one.
I know that this is not a reproducible example, but please bear with me, as this would take some time to repproduce, and i think the problem is clear enough.
Thanks

Comment: how can you bind the data frames together if they have different numbers of columns? What is supposed to happen to the data frames with 4 columns rather than 3?

Comment: I'm using the rbind.fill (from the plyr package) which binds dataframes with a different number of columns

Comment: try `dplyr::bind_rows()`

Comment: Hi Richard, ii'm trying the following 
df <- do.call(bind_rows,comments)
and i'm getting the following error:Error: Argument 2 can't be a list containing data frames

Comment: Also this for loop works, if its of any help for (i in seq(comments))
  assign(paste0("df"), comments[[i]])